# Preserve timestamp in sed command

Tags: linux, sed, rhel

I'm using following sed command to find and replace the string:

```
find dir -name '*.xml' -exec sed -i -e 's/text1/text2/g' {} \;
```

This changes the timestamp of all .xml files inside dir

However, how can I retain old timestamps?

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Using `stat` and `touch`

```
find dir -name '*.xml' -exec bash -c 't=$(stat -c %y "$0"); sed -i -e "s/text1/text2/g" "$0"; touch -d "$t" "$0"' {} \;
```

Using `cp` and `touch`

```
find dir -name '*.xml' -exec bash -c 'cp -p "$0" tmp; sed -i -e "s/text1/text2/g" "$0"; touch -r tmp "$0"' {} \;
```

From manuals:

- cp -p

  > -p same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
- touch -r

  > -r, --reference=FILE
  >   use this file's times instead of current time
- touch -d

  > -d, --date=STRING
  >   parse STRING and use it instead of current time

**Reference:**

- [Preserve modified time stamp after edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43119/preserve-modified-time-stamp-after-edit)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters/131767#131767)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of copying the entire file, you can use

```
touch -r <file>  tmp
```

so you save the timestamp in the tmp file but no content ...

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to insert the timestamp on each file and keeping the original one:

```
(
cd ~/.dotfiles/wiki
for file in *.md; do
    echo "Changing file: $file .."
    t=$(stat -c "%y" "$file") # original timestamp
    new_date=$(date -r "$file" +'%a, %d %b %Y - %H:%M:%S')
    sed -i "1,7s/\(Last Change: \).*/\1 $new_date/g" "$file"
    touch -d "$t" "$file"
done
)
```

In my case the files I needed to change where my markdown folders inside my wiki folder